# iterative binary search implementation in f#

Tags: f#, binary-search

I am trying to write a binary search in f#, but stumbled at a problem:

```
let find(words:string[]) (value:string) =
    let mutable mid = 0
    let mutable fpos = 0
    let mutable lpos = words.Length - 1

    while fpos < lpos do
        mid <- (fpos + lpos) / 2
        if value < words.[mid] then
            lpos <- mid
        else if value > words.[mid] then
            fpos <- mid
        else if value = words.[mid] then
            true

    false
```

It is giving error at the line which says `true` saying it expected an expression of type `unit()` instead got `bool`. What is the correct way to write this function?

**Edit:**

Temporarily I took to writing as follows:

```
let find(words:string[]) (value:string) =
    let mutable mid = 0
    let mutable fpos = 0
    let mutable lpos = words.Length - 1
    let ret = false                
    while fpos < lpos && ret = false do
        mid <- (fpos + lpos) / 2
        if value < words.[mid] then
            lpos <- mid
        else if value > words.[mid] then
            fpos <- mid
        else if value = words.[mid] then
            ret <- true                           

    ret
```

But execution wise I think I am doing a lot of operations here than intended...

Comment: ..it does not work: see my comments to Gene's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a recursive function:

```
let find(words:string[]) (value:string) =
  let rec findRec fpos lpos =
    if fpos > lpos then
      false
    else
      let mid = (fpos + lpos) / 2
      if value < words.[mid] then
        findRec fpos (mid-1)
      else if value > words.[mid] then
        findRec (mid+1) lpos
      else
        true
  findRec 0 (words.Length-1)
```

Non-recursive version (adapted from Gene's answer):

```
let find (words: string[]) (value:string) =
    let mutable mid = 0
    let mutable fpos = 0
    let mutable lpos = words.Length - 1
    let mutable cont = true                
    while fpos <= lpos && cont do
        mid <- (fpos + lpos) / 2
        match sign(value.CompareTo(words.[mid])) with
        | -1 -> lpos <- mid-1
        | 1 -> fpos <- mid+1
        | _ -> cont <- false   
    not cont
```

But I think that the recursive version is preferable: more idiomatic, as efficient as the iterative one because it uses tail calls.

Comment: @deostroll Why? With this implementation it's a tail call, so you're not going to hit a Stack Overflow. This is a great case where F#'s recursion shines.

Comment: Because "recursion is the goto of FP". and "baby code is good". too much kool aid I know. there is some truth to it though...

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, your algo would not terminate for `value` greater, than the rightmost `words` element (easy test case is `find [|"a";"b";"c";"d"|] "e"`).

<del>This matter being corrected and throwing in few minor optimizations, the final interactive implementation is not likely can be shorter, than below</del>

<del>`let find (words: string[]) (value:string) =

  let mutable lpos = words.Length - 1

  if value.CompareTo(words.[lpos]) > 0 then

    false

  else

    let mutable mid = 0

    let mutable fpos = 0

    let mutable cont = true

    while fpos < lpos && cont do

      mid <- (fpos + lpos) / 2

      match sign(value.CompareTo(words.[mid])) with

      | -1 -> lpos <- mid

      | 1 -> fpos <- mid

      | _ -> cont <- false

  not cont`</del>

**UPDATE:** That's what happens when putting answer in a rush and without a computer around :(. The content striked-through above is not something to be proud of. As [MiMo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920539/mimo) has [already took care](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20291398/917053) of all problems in the snippet above I'll try something different to vindicate myself, namely, try demonstrating how MiMo's recursive implementation after tail-call recursion elimination turns almost literally into his non-recursive one.

We'll do this in two steps: first use a pseudo-code with labels and gotos to illustrate what compiler does for eliminating this form of tail recursion, and then convert pseudo-code back into F# for getting an imperative version.

```
// Step 1 - pseudo-code with tail recursion substituted by goto
let find(words:string[]) (value:string) =
    let mutable fpos = 0
    let mutable lpos = words.Length - 1
    findRec:
        match fpos - lpos > 0 with
        | true -> return false
        | _ -> let mid = (fpos + lpos) / 2
               match sign(value.CompareTo(words.[mid])) with
               | -1 -> lpos <- mid - 1
                       goto findRec
               | 1 ->  fpos <- mid + 1
                       goto findRec
               | _ -> return true
```

Now, in absence of `goto` we should come up with an equivalent construction while staying within legit set of F# constructions. The easiest approach would be using `while...do` construction in concert with a mutable `state` variable capable simultaneously of signaling `while` when to stop and carrying return value. A tuple of two Booleans would be sufficient for this purpose:

```
// Step 2 - conversion of pseudo-code back to F#
let find(words:string[]) (value:string) =
    let mutable fpos = 0
    let mutable lpos = words.Length - 1
    let mutable state = (true,false)
    while (fst state) do
        match fpos - lpos > 0 with
        | true -> state <- (false,false)
        | _ -> let mid = (fpos + lpos) / 2
               match sign(value.CompareTo(words.[mid])) with
               | -1 -> lpos <- mid - 1
               | 1 -> fpos <- mid + 1
               | _ -> state <- (false,true)
    snd state
```

Summing up, the difference between "a-la compiler optimized" recursive version and hand-picked imperative one is insignificant, indeed, which should, in my opinion, make evident that correctly arranged recursive version performance-wise is equivalent to imperative version, but, given conversion performed by compiler, leaves no space for blunders of stateful coding.

Comment: ...it does not work if `words` contains only one item (the loop exits immediately)

Comment: It also goes in an infinite loop if `value` is equal to the last item of `words`

Comment: @MiMo: thanks for pointing out more problems; shouldn't respond in a rush without rechecking of original implementation :(.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a recursive solution like this:

```
let find (xs: _ []) x =
  let rec loop i0 i2 =
    match i2-i0 with
    | 0 -> false
    | 1 -> xs.[i0]=x
    | di ->
        let i1 = i0 + di/2
        let c = compare x xs.[i1]
        if c<0 then loop i0 i1
        else c=0 || loop i1 i2
  loop 0 xs.Length
```

F# converts the tail calls into gotos, of course:

```
internal static bool loop@4<a>(a[] xs, a x, int i0, int i2)
{
    a a;
    while (true)
    {
        int num = i2 - i0;
        switch (num)
        {
        case 0:
            return false;
        case 1:
            goto IL_50;
        default:
        {
            int i3 = i0 + num / 2;
            a = xs[i3];
            int c = LanguagePrimitives.HashCompare.GenericComparisonIntrinsic<a>(x, a);
            if (c < 0)
            {
                a[] arg_37_0 = xs;
                a arg_35_0 = x;
                int arg_33_0 = i0;
                i2 = i3;
                i0 = arg_33_0;
                x = arg_35_0;
                xs = arg_37_0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (c == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                a[] arg_4A_0 = xs;
                a arg_48_0 = x;
                int arg_46_0 = i3;
                i2 = i2;
                i0 = arg_46_0;
                x = arg_48_0;
                xs = arg_4A_0;
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    return true;
    IL_50:
    a = xs[i0];
    return LanguagePrimitives.HashCompare.GenericEqualityIntrinsic<a>(a, x);
}

public static bool find<a>(a[] xs, a x)
{
    return File1.loop@4<a>(xs, x, 0, xs.Length);
}
```